# White label iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, android-productflavors

I have to white label an iOS app but I can't figure out the best approach for that.

I know that Android has "Product Flavors" that allows you to customize an app and create many versions of it in the same project.

I didn't find a builtin solution for do the same in an iOS project.

My project uses Fabric, Branch.io and other libraries that requires custom configurations for each white label app.

In this case, should I just create a branch and work on it or there is a better approach similar to Flavors in Android?

Comment: Search for `using Xcode targets` ... won't be exactly the same, but it can be used to get similar results.

Answer (score 3):

Use different Targets to break up the different "favours".

[image]

Another thing to consider is using .xcassets and adding them to the different targets for the different images use in the app

And finally look into .xcconfig if you want different variables across your app. Using GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS will be necessary for this

Answer (score -2):

Apple will now reject all white label apps, see this : https://blog.summitsync.com/did-apple-just-crush-white-label-apps-4aee14d00b78

Comment: Please could you enhance your answer by bringing in the relevant content from the link.

Comment: The guideline in question is the 4.2.6, which says that "Apps created from a commercialized template or app generation service will be rejected unless they are submitted directly by the provider of the app’s content.". So, it's ok to publish a white label app as long as it's published by the provider of the app’s content.

Comment: The link shared is not relevant to the question